# Python: Repeat lines of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to repeat the lines of a dataframe such that the id remains unique by appending an index to the id.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["a1", "a2"], "value": [["x", "y", "z"], ["x"]]})
Out[31]: 
   id      value
0  a1  [ x, y, z]
1  a2        [x]
```

I want to get the following.

```
   id      value
0  a1-1        x
1  a1-2        y
2  a1-3        z
3  a2-1        x
```

I able to repeat the lines using `np.repeat` but not able to keep the id unique.

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.drop(["value"], axis=1).values.repeat([3,1], axis=0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction, here I am using `repeat`

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(df.value.str.len()),'value':df.value.sum()})

s.assign(id=s.id.astype(str)+'-'+(s.groupby('id').cumcount()+1).astype(str))
Out[473]: 
     id value
0  a1-1     x
0  a1-2     y
0  a1-3     z
1  a2-1     x
```